# Mongo Aggregation sort not working as expected

Tags: mongodb, sorting

```
db.getCollection('messages').aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "user": ObjectId('620d0484ff8fedc8500c9d05'),
      "exp": false
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": { "thread": "$thread" },
      "unread": { "$max": "$unseen" },
      "total": { "$sum": 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": { "idate": -1 }
  },
  { "$skip": 0 },
  { "$limit": 4 }
])
```

I want to sum each messages of the thread.  Each message comes a different time, I want to put the last message date as the result and sort with last message date.

Result comes like this

```
{
    thread: ObjectId("620d0a23ff8fedc8500c9d29")
}   false   2
{
    thread: ObjectId("620d0a23ff8fedc8500c0000")
}   true    1
```

Sample data each message comes with

```
db.getCollection("messages").insert( {
    _id: ObjectId("620d0a23ff8fedc8500c9d29"),
    idate: ISODate("2022-02-16T14:58:51.196Z"),
    unseen: false,
    user: ObjectId("620d0484ff8fedc8500c9d05"),
    thread: ObjectId("620d0a23ff8fedc8500c9d29"),
} );

db.getCollection("messages").insert( {
    _id: ObjectId("620d0a23ff8fedc8500c9d30"),
    idate: ISODate("2022-02-16T14:28:51.196Z"),
    unseen: true,
    user: ObjectId("620d0484ff8fedc8500c9d05"),
    thread: ObjectId("620d0a23ff8fedc8500c9d29"),
} );

db.getCollection("messages").insert( {
    _id: ObjectId("620d0a23ff8fedc8500c9e13"),
    idate: ISODate("2022-02-14T14:22:50.008Z"),
    unseen: false,
    user: ObjectId("620d0484ff8fedc8500c9d05"),
    thread: ObjectId("620d0a23ff8fedc8500c0000"),
} );
```

Comment: Schema is wildduck email schema

Comment: that's because you don't have  field  `idate` after your `$group` stage?

Comment: If I use idate in group how can I sum the fields. idate is not the same

Comment: your question is not clear to me, all i know is that you're trying to sort by `idate` after your `$group` stage and there is not field with that name. please add more information like the smaple input and your expected output.

Comment: Thank you 1sina1. If you dont ask the right question I won't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

First put the lasted message date to the group

```
{"$group": .....
,"date": {"$last":'$idate'},
....
```

then sort the new date column

```
{"$sort": {"date": -1}},
```